# How can I automatically toggle hardware graphics acceleration?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, automation, directx, hardware-acceleration

My laptop computer has (probably) corrupted graphics card memory and it causes some bizarre errors such as colorful dots appearing all over the screen, cursor jumping up and down and freezing occasionally. I noticed that the problems go away when I turn off HW acceleration in Windows. Whenever I want to play a movie, the picture is blocky unless I reactivate HW acceleration.

Doing this manually is annoying and it takes some time so **I would like to make a little program to automate the process of disabling or enabling HW acceleration on all displays** (equivalent to moving the slider all the way to the left in screen settings). I have no previous experience with programming for Windows so I will appreciate if someone can at least point me in the right direction.

I am a cheapskate, buying a new computer is not an option since this one works quite well while I keep HW acceleration disabled.

**Edit**: The acceleration level is in my case stored in the registry key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Video{85D18855-5163-4CFC-8A71-222DCC03C001}\0000

"Acceleration.Level"=dword:00000005

The key is not there by default, deleting it and changing color depth switches HW acceleration back on.

Comment: I'd imagine it would be easier to adjust what backend your media player uses to output the movies- at least if you use one like VLC. You could switch to, say, the `Windows GDI video output` plugin in VLC, which should work fine (assuming your CPU can handle the video).

Comment: That didn't help as GDI seems to be the default fallback in case DirectX is unavailable. I already do the decoding on CPU, the post processing is accelerated.

Comment: @JohnEye: I know buying a new computer is not an option for you right now, but honestly, it gets to a point where you really need to get a new machine. This is one of those times. Windows XP? Crappy graphics card behaving weirdly? In 2012? Don't make yourself suffer more than you already do. Seriously, save up and make the investment for a much better machine.

Comment: **Have you updated your video drivers?**  Are your overclocking?  Display corruption rarely means damaged hardware.

Comment: Ben Voigt: Yes, my video drivers are up to date and no, I am not overclocking. I am pretty confident in my claim that hardware issue is to blame, because I witnessed as the problem got progressively worse over the course of several weeks. Also, it seems to be tied to what I believe are bit shifts on the underlying hardware - the artifacts appear whenever I am scrolling on a website and they seem to be caused by bits being corrupted at the same place in video memory. This creates columns of the same color on the screen. This problem is really quite remarkable and very interesting to observe.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would almost agree, except in the case of bad memory. Memory in general is the root of most artifacts.

Comment: @peachykeen: Yes, but it's usually caused by violation of the timing specs, not hardware damage.  And drivers do often screw up setup and hold time in really weird ways due to power management switching clock rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A side note: Serious problems might be developing...

These errors are a sign that there is something wrong with your graphics card and if you don't handle the chance is very high that your Graphics Card will continue to decline to the point where you can't even use your computer anymore.

I'm also pretty clueless why you aren't able to use your computer with HW acceleration while you can watch a video just fine, perhaps you could consider turning off DWM if you are using it as that could be the culprit sofware-wise and doesn't need you to turn HW acceleration off anymore.

However, this is essence a hardware problem so you might plan on upgrading at least your Graphics Card; or at least keep some budget aside for it, in case it decides to fail sooner or later...

### How one automates it anyway...

You should be able to get around with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

In the [Documentation](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/), you'll find tutorials on basic things. The first three should suffice to understand how to respond to Window events.

Then, it's just a matter of making a `WHILE` loop in which you wait for the window to be active, then enable HW acceleration, then wait for the window to be inactive, then disable HW acceleration; after which the loop repeats. That way, whenever you watch a video it's accelerated and otherwise it is not.

If you did the installation tutorial, you can easily automatically perform the actions to turn the HW acceleration on and off, it might be required to provide <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `SendKeys` in order to get to the slider. After which you can probably send a left or right arrow (perhaps a few times?) to slide it in the right direction.

As I'm thinking that you are referring to the HW acceleration feature of your graphics card, I can't write this for you as I don't have your graphics card and in the most cases don't even have its drivers.

Comment: I can't disable DWM because there is no DWM in Windows XP. I also cannot upgrade the graphics card because it happens to be soldered onto the motherboard of the laptop. Please move this question back to Stackoverflow. Good idea with AutoIt, but I am looking for programming advice, not a kludge.

Comment: @JohnEye: Please flag your question and ask for it to be migrated back to Stack Overflow, I can't flag it as I have already flagged it for another reason...

Comment: @JohnEye: Also, AutoIt is not a kludge as you can call its DLLs if you don't feel like scripting. If you want to go a step further, you could as well call the Windows APIs yourself instead of using the simplicity of AutoIt. Alternatively, look with Process Monitor what file / registry part is changed and manually change it and reload the driver. All that can also be done through the Windows API...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wanted to do it by calling the Windows APIs in the first place. Sadly, I was unable to find any useful information on the subject so I asked here. If it is just a matter of changing registry values and reloading the driver, the answer could be easier to find. Is this what causes the brief blackout when I disable HW acceleration manually? If so, I could be halfway done as I have already diffed the registry before and after.

Comment: @JohnEye: I'm not completely sure whether it's actually stored in the registry but you might be able to find it in the diff, other options include something written to the disk or the graphics card. But the registry is indeed the most prevalent place for it to be. I'm not sure how the driver / graphics card is reloaded. I see two possible (alternative?) solutions: Switching the resolution or color depth twice (although that makes it flicker twice), or disable and enable the card in device manager (dunno how to do that programatically).

Comment: @JohnEye: It would help if you emphasized the programming part of your question.  If you surround text with double asterisks, like `**text**`, it'll be displayed in bold.  But finding registry settings is actually on topic on SU, not SO.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think you meant to comment on his quention, but I think it is this part: `I would like to make a little program to automate the process of disabling or enabling HW acceleration on all displays` He has already found the registry settings (or at least the difference, which would most likely contain the setting); so, he now needs a programmatic way to get the settings loaded in, two of which I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thank you, I edited the question accordingly. I know what the registry entries are, that was easy. I am looking for the API calls.

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: As a matter of fact, it really does flicker twice. Thanks for the tip!